# eBay API convert Shipping Address to International Address formats

Tags: c#, paypal, ebay-api

I am building eBay application that fetches the buyer shipping address

I am calling `GetOrders` http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/getorders.html

and receiving this xml in return:

```
<AddressAttribute type="AddressAttributeCodeType"> AddressAttributeType (string) </AddressAttribute>
    <AddressID> string </AddressID>
    <AddressOwner> AddressOwnerCodeType </AddressOwner>
    <CityName> string </CityName>
    <Country> CountryCodeType </Country>
    <CountryName> string </CountryName>
    <ExternalAddressID> string </ExternalAddressID>
    <Name> string </Name>
    <Phone> string </Phone>
    <PostalCode> string </PostalCode>
    <ReferenceID> string </ReferenceID>
    <StateOrProvince> string </StateOrProvince>
    <Street1> string </Street1>
    <Street2> string </Street2>
</AddressAttribute >
```

I am trying to understand how to convert the shipping address to International shipping format
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_(geography)

This means:
If the country is `Finland` than the result should be the following string:

```
Company
Name or Department
Street name + number + *apartment number (optional)
Postal code + Town
Country
```

If the country is `Iceland` than the result should be the following string:

```
Name
Streetname + Number
Complements
Postal code + Place
```

If the country is `USA` that the result should be:

```
Name of addressee
House number and street name
Name of town, State abbreviation + ZIP code
(typical handwritten format)
```

etc.

How can I do that automatically?

Comment: you can read the XML file in your C# code and set format as per requirement?

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a little page to get my eBay listings details with PHP. I am not there yet, but once I go into the address printing I plan to work that out too.

I am using GetItemTransactions to get the address details. That call has:

```
<Name>John Doe</Name>
<Street>Nowhere St. 11</Street>
<Street1>Nowhere St. 11</Street1>
<CityName>Berlin</CityName>
<StateOrProvince>
<Country>DE</Country>
<CountryName>Germany</CountryName>
<Phone>Invalid Request</Phone>
<PostalCode>11508</PostalCode>
```

I plan to use this default format:

```
<Name>
<Street>
<Street1>  // if not the same
<PostalCode><CityName>
<CountryName>
```

And for UK, US etc I do a simple:

```
if($Country == 'UK|UK|CA|AU') 
{
echo $CityName." ".$StateOrProvince." ".$PostalCode;
}
```

I think with a bit of fine tuning and monitoring in the beginning it's very easy.